# Is there a pandas function that can count each mach number in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas for data cleanup, and what my problem is i hope to count the numbers of values but relate on two columns looks like

```
    type_name  cluster_group
0           0              1
1           4              2
2           1              1
3           2              2
4           4              0
..        ...            ...
95          0              3
96          2              2
97          1              3
98          2              4
99          1              2

find out below

type_name  cluster_group  cluster_group_numbers
        0              0                      1
        0              1                      3
        0              2                      5
        0              3                     21
        0              4                     16
      ...            ...                    ...
        4              0                      8
        4              1                      3
        4              2                      2
        4              3                     15
        4              4                      6
```

The way I try now is split it into two steps, first to get type_name out by

```
tmp_df = tmp[tmp["type_name"] == i]
```

And used grouby().count() to count cluster_groups, and the whole code look like this

```
for i in range(5):
    tmp_df = tmp[tmp["type_name"] == i]
    print(tmp_df.groupby(["cluster_groups"]).count())
```

But this do not make my work faster and cleaner, so here to ask for help~

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more clearly?

Comment: Are you looking for `df.groupby('cluster_groups').value_counts()`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Just curious, how do you get the `cluster_group_number` value as above?

Comment: @BeRT2me Yes~ Thanks for you answer~ This is exactly what I need ~

Comment: @Zero What I want to do is to get the number of occurrences of a value, but what I need is the number of individual occurrences, which relies on two different coloumns , so I'm stuck here. The answer from `BeRT2me` is what i need~ Thanks for looking the question~

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew I hope i get it XDD，The way i try is use a for loop to get each subset of pandas datatframe to counts the numbers and reset back to my dataframe. `BeRT2me` gives the answer~